# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when using execute immediate

Tags: plsql, ora-00933

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  INTO l_entry_found 
  FROM hera.hera_user@iam 
 WHERE username = docm.eb_key;
```

without execute immediate it works.

```
execute immediate'
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_entry_found FROM hera.hera_user@iam WHERE 
      username = docm.eb_key;';
```

However throws an `ora-00933`.

What could be the Problem and how may i solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't use `select into` in dynamic sql

Comment: You also need to remove the `;` inside your SQL String.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use `select into` in dynamic SQL
and you do not need a semicolon either

```
declare
  l_entry number(10);
begin

  execute immediate'
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hera.hera_user@iam WHERE 
        username = '''||docm.eb_key||'''' INTO l_entry;
end;
```

Comment: does every variable inside of the execute immediate Need to be defined there as well? as im now getting an invalid identifier on docm.eb_key

Comment: If your select hase more than one column as result then you need a variable for each column

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues; say you have a table like

```
create table someTable(userName varchar2(100))
```

and a code like :

```
declare
    someVariable    varchar2(100);
    l_entry_found   number;
begin
    someVariable := 'someName';
    --
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_entry_found
    FROM someTable
    WHERE username = someVariable;
end;
```

If you wat to switch to dynamic SQL, you need to

- remove the semicolon
- use bind variables to pass your parameter
- move the `INTO` outside the dynamic part

Your code could be:

```
declare
    someVariable    varchar2(100);
    l_entry_found   number;
begin
    someVariable := 'someName';
    --
    execute immediate 
    'SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM someTable
    WHERE username = :bindVar'
    into l_entry_found
    using someVariable;
end;
```

Here I assume that you have a good reason to switch to dynamic SQL, for example, your table name could change based on some parameter; if not, plain SQL is good enough for your task.

Comment: The code will be installed in our production, but will only be used on testservers. The DB link .@iam does not exist on production, so having it without dynamic SQL would give us an productive invalid. However my main Problem at this Point is, that i Need a Loop variable inside of the dynamic SQL which i cant use there. The whole Thing is just a small sleeper procedure which does nothing unless waiting for when some data arrived in the .@iam DB. Maybe ill just replace it with a hardwired wait 10 minutes if there is no Workaround for my Problem.

Comment: procedure check#hera
  is
  l_cnt number := 0;

  procedure check#docm
    is
    l_entry_found number;
    l_eb_key varchar2(10);


    begin
      for docm in (SELECT eb_key from tst_migr$eb_docm) loop
      l_eb_key := docm.eb_key;
      execute immediate' SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hera.hera_user@iam WHERE username = l_eb_key' INTO l_entry_found;
        if l_entry_found = 0 and l_cnt < 10 then
          dbms_lock.sleep(10);
          l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
          check#docm;
        end if;
      end loop;
    end check#docm;
  begin
  check#docm;


end check#hera;

Answer (score 0):

The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement executes a dynamic SQL statement or anonymous PL/SQL block. You can use it to issue SQL statements that cannot be represented directly in PL/SQL, or to build up statements where you do not know all the table names, WHERE clauses, and so on in advance

[image]

#### Continuing with your question

```
-- Case using 1 output column 'COUNT(*)', 1 filter variable 'eb_key'
DECLARE
  --
  eb_key VARCHAR2(100) := 'something';
  l_entry_found number;
  --
BEGIN 
  execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hera.hera_user@iam WHERE username = :eb_key;' USING eb_key INTO l_entry_found;
END;

-- Case using 2 output column 'COUNT(*)', 3 filter variable 'eb_key'
DECLARE
  --
  eb_column1 VARCHAR2(100) := 'something';
  eb_column2 VARCHAR2(100) := 'something';
  l_entry_found1 number;
  l_entry_found2 number;
  --
BEGIN 
  execute immediate 'SELECT column1, column2 FROM hera.hera_user@iam WHERE username = :eb_1 AND lastname = :eb_2;' USING eb_column1, eb_column2 INTO l_entry_found1,l_entry_found2;
END;
```